# iMovie: safe to delete Render Files?

Tags: finder, imovie

I'm hoping to slim down the size of my 50gb iMovie library. I noticed that a huge chunk of space (like 20gb) is taken up by the contents of a "Render Files" folder in one of my Event folders.

> You can see the "Render Files" folder by right-clicking/control-clicking your iMovie Library and choosing "Show Package Contents". Then open one of your Event folders. The "Render Files" folder is in there.

What's the deal with those files? Can I safely trash them? Will iMovie rebuild them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can delete them, but to make sure, you can drag them to the desktop, open iMovie and see if it works. If it works, you can delete the files.

Comment: Brilliant. Why didn't I think of that? I removed them and fired up iMovie... everything seems to still be intact! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, and iMovie can even delete (all) of them for you.

Go to iMovie > Preferences and click "Delete" next to Render Files (last item on the bottom for me).

[image: iMovie preferences]

It will warn you about deleting data, and that it may have to be regenerated in the future.

[image: iMovie delete warning]

Inspecting my iMovie library with Finder after this operation revealed that it cleared the Render Files directory and freed up ~60GB from my disk.